# Assigning randomly generated integers to string output in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a random fact generator that takes a randomly generated number (in this case 1 -10) and assigns that number to a string output that tells the user a random fact.

So far this is all I have been able to piece together code wise:

```
#Greeting
a = "Hello, who am I speaking to?"
print("Welcome, " + input(a) + "!" + " Lets see what fact you rolled...")

#Random Number Generator
import random
for x in range (1):
    randomNumber = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(randomNumber)

#Loop function   
def check_val(randomNumber, title, answer):
        while True:
            if input(randomNumber) == title:
                print(answer)
                break
            else:
                print("I dont know.")

#Facts
def fact():

            randomNumber, answer = {}, {}
            randomNumber[1] = ([1])
            answer[1] = "Fact1"
            randomNumber[2] = ([2])
            answer[2] = "Fact2"
            randomNumber[3] = ([3])
            answer[3] = "Fact3"
            randomNumber[4] = ([4])
            answer[4] = "Fact4"
            randomNumber[5] = ([5])
            answer[5] = "Fact5"
            for k in randomNumber:
                check_val(randomNumber[k], k, answer[k])


fact()
```

When running this code, I get the following output:

Hello, who am I speaking to?j
Welcome, j! Lets see what fact you rolled...
5
[1]

I am not able to take that random integer (5) and assign it to random fact #5.

Any ideas on how to assign these random integers to usable output?

Comment: It seems like you've written some of your code without really understanding all the things you're using. One of the most useful techniques for trying to solve a programming problem is rubber duck debugging (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) - which involves explaining what you think the code is doing step by step. Can you edit your question to do that? It will help people trying to answer understand what you *want* to do, and where you might be going wrong in your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Hey bud you got a lot going on in here, you can simple this down using a `list` to store your facts, heres a better format that you can build off of.
As mentioned by @JonClements we can use `random.randrange(len(facts))` this will make our code more adaptable if we want to alter the amount of facts in our list.

```
import random

while True:
    name = input("\nHello, Who am I speaking to?\n")
    print(f"\nWelcome, {name}! Lets see what you rolled..."

    facts = [ 
        'Fact one',
        'Fact two',
        'Fact three',
        'Fact four',
        'Fact five',
        'Fact six',
        'Fact seven',
        'Fact eight',
        'Fact nine',
        'Fact ten'
    ]   

    selection = random.randrange(len(facts))

    print(facts[selection])
```

Comment: if your not using the integer, you can just use random.choise(facts)

Comment: @JonasWolff of course, I was considering this while writing this but OP original goal was  "Any ideas on how to assign these random integers to usable output?" so I wanted to take the route of passing a random `int`

Comment: @JonasWolff But I agree that is more efficient, was trying to tailor response more towards OP request

Comment: @vash_the_stampede careful with your indices here... `randint` is inclusive of the end range so you'll never pick Fact One (index 0 - remember indices start at 0 in Python) and if you happen to pick 10 as the number, you'll get an `IndexError` trying to print the fact.... You're probably better off putting the facts first, picking a random number by using `selection = random.randrange(len(facts))` and then making sure you add 1 if printing the fact number.

Comment: Oh wow I missed that @JonClements, I'm aware just rushed the output will update, I'm slacking, let you down :/

Comment: @JonClements I just altered the range to `(0, 9)`

Comment: @vash_the_stampede okay... so let's hope no facts are removed - causing a potential `IndexError` when the upper range is picked or new facts are added which will never be chosen... putting the facts first and using its length to pick a number avoids all that... up to you though :)

Comment: @JonClements I agree I in the past myself have used `len` for my `randomint` I'm just assuming OP skill level he is going to cap this program at 10 facts as stated in the question, don't want to deviate too far and cause more confusion

Comment: Capping it's fine... but removing them will cause exceptions... but yeah... as long as they keep it exactly to 10 it'll work... I just figured if you're trying to help the OP learn some best practices you might as well go the whole hog and swap two lines around :)

Comment: Thank you! I am very new to Python (and programming in general). I appreciate the help and multiple perspectives. Ill see if I can get it to work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Greeting
a = "Hello, who am I speaking to?"
print("Welcome, " + input(a) + "!" + " Lets see what fact you rolled...")

#Random Number Generator
import random
for x in range (1):
    randomNumber = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(randomNumber)   <--- your printing 5

#Loop function   
def check_val(randomNumber, title, answer):
        while True:
            if input(randomNumber) == title: <--- answer argument which were passed was [1] remember so it asks you to write something with the text [1]
                print(answer)
                break
            else:
                print("I dont know.")

#Facts
def fact():

            randomNumber, answer = {}, {}   <--- your 5 nol longer exist because you now overwrote it with a dict
            randomNumber[1] = ([1])
            answer[1] = "Fact1"
            randomNumber[2] = ([2])
            answer[2] = "Fact2"
            randomNumber[3] = ([3])
            answer[3] = "Fact3"
            randomNumber[4] = ([4])
            answer[4] = "Fact4"
            randomNumber[5] = ([5])
            answer[5] = "Fact5"
            for k in randomNumber:    <--- # now it's iterating over the dict, and since you wrote 1 first that is most likely to be the one it finds first in the memory though there no order here
                check_val(randomNumber[k], k, answer[k])


fact()
```